# Can I create single instance of Get.find<>()?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Currently to display value from `controller` I am using next construction:

```
Get.find<XMLFilesStatController>().foo.value,
Get.find<XMLFilesStatController>().bar.value,
Get.find<XMLFilesStatController>().baz.value,
```

Can I create in class single instance that point to `Get.find<XMLFilesStatController>()` ?

Something like:
`var xmlCtrl = Get.find<XMLFilesStatController>();`

and then use it as: `xmlCtrl.foo`?

I tried to do it like:

```
class XMLProcessingStatisticView extends StatelessWidget {
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var xmlCtrl = Get.find<XMLFilesStatController>();
```

On main.dart I am creating:

```
main() {
  //....
  Get.lazyPut<XMLFilesStatController>(() => XMLFilesStatController());

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

So instance `XMLFilesStatController` is initialized. But I need way to shortcut `Get.find`

But got an error:

```
errors.dart:202 Uncaught (in promise) Error: "XMLFilesStatController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(XMLFilesStatController())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>XMLFilesStatController())"
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you using `Get.put(...)`?  It may be related to the depedency only being available when the widget is built. Try moving the variable `dt` inside the build method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Get.put(XMLFilesStatController())` or `Get.lazyPut(()=>XMLFilesStatController())` at first. Then you can create your object by calling `var xmlCtrl = Get.find<XMLFilesStatController>();` .

If you want your `XMLFilesStatController` object to be permanent i.e. you want to create the object for only one time and use it for whole app lifecycle, then you need to do this `Get.put(XMLFilesStatController(),permanent=true)`

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do exactly what you described, but your problem is that you haven't instantiated `XMLFilesStatController` yet. You first have to use `Get.put(XMLFilesStatController());` or `Get.lazyPut(()=>XMLFilesStatController());`.

After that you can just use `var xmlCtrl = Get.find<XMLFilesStatController>();` like you said.

Take a look at [dependency management](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx#dependency-management).

Comment: could I create `Get.put` not in Widget but in `main()` ?

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov Yes, you can, but that would make your instance available in your whole application. Make sure that is what you want.